# How to get another variable type from sql query

Tags: python

From this query...

```
self.cur.execute("""SELECT pub FROM "20091229"
                 GROUP BY pub ORDER BY pub""")
```

I get the following list with tuples back.

```
>>[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```

But I need only a list or a list without decimal points in the tuples.
Something like these:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

or

```
[(1), (2), (3)]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `[(1,), (2,), (3,)]` - these are not decimal points (commas). These are tuple elements delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better if you tell us what module do you use to work with db. Also i am not sure but your query can be optimized to something like this 'SELECT DISTINCT pub FROM "20091229" ORDER BY pub'

I know that nobody here likes reduce but it could be also used here:

```
from operator import add

reduce(lambda res,x: add(res, x), [(1,), (2,), (3,)])
```

OR in case there could be only list of single item tuples:

```
from operator import itemgetter
map(itemgetter(0), [(1,), (2,), (3,)])
```

Comment: Maybe it is not the best way to solve it but it works. :) Now, I just get a tuple back: (1, 2, 3). 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you, @The_Fox - there are a lot of ways to do things in python and selecting the best is always depends only from you.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
li = [tup[0] for tup in li]
```

Please note, a tuple get's written like this `(1,)`, because `(1)` would imply mathematical brackets. Also, it seems you are trying to print a list, consider using a dedicated printing function.

Comment: I need a list because i want to use this list in a later sql query as variable and with the decimal points i get an error.

Comment: @The_Fox: The problem is is that you are using `str(li)`. Consider proper formatting the list.